# client server communication solution

Tags: java, client-server

I'd like to ask if my solution is OK or if there is a better way to do this.

I have an Android client and a Tomcat server. I send a few words (as a POST saved in JSON) to server and server sends me back a JSON with an article containing those words.
Suppose it's a public app, so a lot of people may send a 'request' for an article.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, or if there's another and proper way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: It seems ok to me, but since you ask this question, you must have some specific doubts about this. Could you explain your doubts?

Comment: I'm never sure about anything :-) Anyway, I will defend this solution in front of a committee so I have to be prepared for this kinda questions: "why this, why not that" and such... And I'm not so skilled so I rather ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you android client appears to be "Getting" an article you might consider using a GET request as opposed to a POST request, however the differences are trivial. Otherwise your solution sounds perfectly fine. Look into "REST" and "SOAP" as different options for writing web service APIs.

Comment: what about the variable number of words I send with my request? Doesn't that matter?

Comment: No particularly, just encode your query words in way you can parse them easily, for example, q=term1,term2,term3